# rEFInd bypassed on MacBook with Mac, Windows, Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, refind

I had dual boot of Mac and Windows on one drive. I've decided to install Ubuntu on SSD using rEFInd. After installation I have (Mac+Win)+(Ubuntu). The thing is that, when i start up the laptop in place of rEFInd starts Ubuntu. And only when I press Alt I can see [standard Mac boot options(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVwJ4.jpg).

```
 /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI NO NAME                 536.9 MB   disk0s1
   2:           Linux Filesystem                         247.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Linux Swap                         8.5 GB     disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            599.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                150.0 GB   disk1s4
```

1. Can I uninstall rEFInd without any changes in described boot process?(Because it seems that rEFInd doesn't take action in it)
2. What will happen with boot after I delete rEFInd and ubuntu?
3. Can I change back to MacOS as a first boot(without pressing anything, like it does Ubuntu right now) and make rEFInd to boot Windows or Ubuntu when needed? (Without reinstalling Windows or Mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happened is that Ubuntu has installed GRUB as the primary boot manager on the computer, which is overriding the rEFInd boot. It's unclear from your description if you're able to boot all three OSes from GRUB. If not, or if you don't like GRUB, you can restore rEFInd to be the primary boot loader.

The less invasive but harder way to do this is to use `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu. Type `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see a list of boot options. Look for one that references rEFInd (it may be called "Mac OS X" or something similar, but should refer to the rEFInd binary filename). You can then use the `-o` option to `efibootmgr` to set it to the start of the boot order, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o 0080,0001,0081` if the rEFInd option is `Boot0080` and `Boot0001` and `Boot0081` are things you might want to boot if rEFInd fails to come up for some reason.

The easier but somewhat-overkill way to get rEFInd working again is to re-install it. You should be able to do this either from OS X or from Ubuntu. Once it's re-installed, you should be able to boot any of your OSes from rEFInd. In the case of Ubuntu (and perhaps OS X or Windows), you should be able to do so either directly or via GRUB.

Comment: Hello Rod, I tried using `refind-install` to install refind, but when I rebooted it went straight to (a previously existing) GRUB. I thought `refind-install` would make refind the default thing that boots?

Comment: I removed all traces of GRUB. Now refind simply doesn't boot, and after some time the machine simply goes to OS X. I made a new question for it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/716662/why-wont-bless-make-refind-boot-by-default